# Could an anti-virus program (like Windows Defender) cause memory errors while running larger Java programs?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, heap-memory

I have a program which I run using IntelliJ. Locally, I run it on my Macbook and have never run into issues with memory before, despite it being a larger program.

I recently set up the same code on IntelliJ on a Windows VM. Everytime I open IntelliJ there, it warns me that my anti-virus, Windows Defender, could affect my IDE performance and build speed. I ignored it since I was okay with a slower build speed. However, I've been getting memory errors everytime I run my program; early enough that it keeps it from running anything significant.

The error appears in my logs as shown below:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space             
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
```

I've tried increasing the heap size in multiple ways, restarting the IDE each time, and it just throws the same error. The error gets thrown at the same time too, no matter how large I set the heap size.

Could Windows Defender play a part in causing this error? Is it worth trying to run the program without it on and seeing if it makes a difference?

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: The code is proprietary so I cannot.

Comment: Windows Defender affects the performance of file I/O operations, but it doesn't affect the behavior of the application in other aspects, and it can't lead to OOM exceptions. If the error can be reproduced when running inside the IDE, why don't you simply put a breakpoint at the problematic location and check that the array size is correct?